# Google assistant taking over my app's conversation on certain commands

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-assistant

My app has certain commands that seem to conflict with the Google Assistant's built in behavior. Even though I'm in a conversation with my app and have explicitly asked for a response, the Google Assistant takes over when the user says "Read the note" or "play the tape". In the first case it pops into reading my keep notes. In the second it launches YT music and plays something. I want those commands to be fulfilled by my app!

I've tried training on those specific phrases through the dialogflow console but it didn't seem to help. Is there any way to ensure my app processes all commands while it's in a conversation? Or at least a few specific ones?

I should note, otherwise, commands work perfectly. Even similar ones like "look at the note" work. It's those specific commands causing issues. "Play ____" seems to always launch YT Music though. Commands like "look at the note" go through my TEXT intent and not a fallback intent.

[image: Intent]
[image: More Intent]
[image: The rest]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you update your question to include images of the Intent that you think should be matching, so we can try and duplicate it as closely as possible? The more information you can provide, the better our chances are of helping. See "[ask] a good question" for details.

Comment: @Prisoner Thanks for the response. I've added images of the intent. It's meant to be a bit of a catch all. All other queries get matched to this intent (not a fall back intent) except for when they overlap with GA built-in behavior (Take the note, read the note, play ___")

Comment: Is there any other information you need?